# Facebook Search algorithm and page views

Tags: facebook

I noticed that if I once a while browse through a Facebook page of a person, with whom I have no mutual interests/friends/2nd-tier-friends/region, Facebook Search ranks this person's page higher then my friends in the search suggestions.

When I download "all data about me" from Facebook's settings, that person is not listed there.

Does this mean, that the data that Facebook provides for download is not full? 
Then what is the purpose of it?
Is it defined somewhere that this data should be full?

Answer (score 1):

The search data is in your activity log as described by https://www.facebook.com/help/405183566203254

The flow goes like this

- Click "Download a copy of your Facebook data."
- Presented with a page that has the following

> Download Your Information Get a copy of what you've shared on
>   Facebook.
>
> Start My Archive What's included? Posts, photos and videos you've
>   shared Your messages and chat conversations Info from the About
>   section of your profile And more

- Click and more link

Presented with https://www.facebook.com/help/405183566203254

**About me section**

Information you added to the About section of your Timeline like relationships, work, education, where you live and more. It includes any updates or changes you made in the past and what is currently in the About section of your Timeline.

Available in: Activity Log, Downloaded Info

**Search section**

Searches you’ve made on Facebook.

Available in: Activity Log